# Warning: curl_setopt() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given

Tags: php, curl

Tried to write init function for CURL. But have error

> Warning: curl_setopt() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given

Code is simple.

```
$config['CURLOPT_URL'] = "https://weburl/index.action";
$config['CURLOPT_VERBOSE'] = 0;
$config['CURLOPT_SSLVERSION'] = 3;
$config['CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER'] = FALSE;
$config['CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST'] = 2;
$config['CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION'] = 0;

$tuCurl = curl_init();
foreach($this->config as $key => $val)
{
    curl_setopt($tuCurl, $key, $val);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `curl_setopt_array` ?

Comment: For each of the `$config[]` elements, remove the quotes - ie: `$config[CURLOPT_URL]='https://weburl.blah';`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `$key` should be [constants](http://php.net/manual/en/curl.constants.php) (long type), not string, so

```
$config['CURLOPT_URL'] = "https://weburl/index.action";
$config['CURLOPT_VERBOSE'] = 0;
$config['CURLOPT_SSLVERSION'] = 3;
$config['CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER'] = FALSE;
$config['CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST'] = 2;
$config['CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION'] = 0;
```

should be

```
$config[CURLOPT_URL] = "https://weburl/index.action";
$config[CURLOPT_VERBOSE] = 0;
$config[CURLOPT_SSLVERSION] = 3;
$config[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = FALSE;
$config[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST] = 2;
$config[CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION] = 0;
```

A better way to do this is, however, is use [curl_setopt_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt-array.php) instead of `curl_setopt`.

```
curl_setopt_array($tuCurl, $config);
```

Comment: Thanks. I did not know about the function curl_setopt_array.

Comment: Thank you! I never knew what "param 2 to be long" meant. My issue is different but your answer led me in the right path.

Answer (score 3):

curl_setopt expects one of the CURLOPT_* constants (which are integers) as its second parameter.

You could either use

```
curl_setopt($tuCurl, constant($key), $val); // notice the constant function
```

or use curl_setopt_array and use the constant instead of your array keys (remove the quotes).

Answer (score 1):

The cURL options are constants representing numeric values. You are using them as strings, which is wrong. Do it like this:

```
$config[CURLOPT_URL] = "https://weburl/index.action";
// ...
```